Linebreak on Different Control Codes: Notepad++
I have a file that uses ASCII control code 30, Record Separator, to separate records. Control codes 10, 12, and 13--Line Feed, Form Feed, and Carriage Return--are used in the contained data. I cannot use them.
Notepad++ puts the data all in one line (except the contained line feeds and carriage returns). It is very laggy since the "lines" are ~1 to 10 million characters long. Is there any way I can tell Notepad++ to pretend like control code 30 is a Line Feed and render the data after it on a new line? As a bonus, can I tell it to not render a new line for Line Feed and Carriage Return?
I need to edit data in the records and so I will be saving and modifying the file over time on a server expecting the Record Separators and Line Feeds are part of the data. I cannot simply replace the Record Separators with Line Feeds.

I'm afraid you can't.

@Toto would you happen to know if there are any editors that can?

Why not replace it with new line + random Unicode character that doesn't exist anywhere in the text? Then replace that back with RS. Ofc it could break the flow if the record gets that combo, but I'm not too sure traditional text editors are too suitable for this task anyways

following along the lines of @Destroy666 's thoughts - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492090/least-used-delimiter-character-in-normal-text-ascii-128

can't you programmatically 'edit' the file - using python/ruby/awk/...

@ticktalk I have been using grep to find things, but awk looks very useful for my purposes. Albeit less useful than an interface like notepad++, but useful.
